# JQuery Mobile - dynamically created link not loading new page

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JSON to load some HTML from an external server to my app. I am then using JQuery to create and attach a button to this HTML content. Problem is, when I test it, it doesnt work - I just get the spinning wheel icon.

My Jquery code is:

```
  // attach find on map button
  var coords = $('.event').find('.coords').val();
  mapbutton = '<a class="mapbtn" href="map.html?longlat='+ coords +' "><button class="viewmap">Map</button></a>';
  $('.event').append(mapbutton);
```

The button appears ok, and on inspection in the console the link appears correct. But it just wont link out. I have also tried removing the longlat var and just having plain 
`href="map.html"`

to no avail. Would anyone now how to fix this?

Thanks!

(ps - this is a Cordova/Phonegap project if it matters)

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have a button inside of a link. Try it without the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a proper solution but it seems to work by treating it as an external link by adding `rel="external"` to the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working on PC?

try to this

```
 // attach find on map button
  var coords = $('.event').find('.coords').val();
  mapbutton = '<a class=mapbtn href=map.html?longlat='+ coords +'><button class="viewmap">Map</button></a>';
  $('.event').append(mapbutton);
```

I've changed just removes [""]

I hope that it work

Comment: Thanks but not change there - no its not working on PC or the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Is your external server whitelisted in the config.xml file?